# How do I format a variable argument TCHAR

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions

```
void LogWriter::WriteLog(LPCTSTR log, const char ending, LPTSTR args, ...)
{
    TCHAR str[128] = {0};
    int len = (sizeof(log)/sizeof(TCHAR));
    len += sizeof(ending)/sizeof(char); //might switch ending to TCHAR..might have to

    _stprintf_s(str, len+4, "%s()%c", log, ending);
    myOutput.push(str);
    //used to output to console for testing
    //if (args != NULL)
    //{
    //    va_list argptr;
    //    va_start(argptr, args);
    //    vfprintf(stdout, args, argptr);
    //    va_end(argptr);
    //}
}
```

so that was a cool way to print my log to the console.. but now I want to be able to choose where I put my log. I decided to just redirect wcout either to a file, or to the console. when I was outputing to the console it was super easy to do this because I only had

```
void LogWriter::WriteLog(const char* log, const char ending, char* args, ...)
{
    std::wcout << log << "(";
    if (args != NULL)
    {
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr, args);
        vfprintf(stdout, args, argptr);
        va_end(argptr);
    }
    std::wcout << ")" << ending << std::endl;
}
```

and life was good...when it was a single threaded program and all logging went to the console. So I figured I'd use a queue to temporarily store lines in my log. In a seperate thread I empty the queue and sleep for 500ms. This works well (i haven't done a bunch of testing on this yet for speed/performance) but with the sprintf function it's giving me gibberish in the output. If i get rid of the sprintf all together and just push the log to my queue it outputs the string correctly. Leads me to that i'm doing it wrong for sprintf, but i also need/want the variable arguments to go in there too..... hmm that might mean a change to something. I have a few macros that this might affect..

```
#define WRITE_START LogWriter::WriteLog(__FUNCTION__, '+')
#define WRITE_STARTF(_smsg, ...) LogWriter::WriteLog(__FUNCTION__, '+', _smsg, __VA_ARGS__) 

//example of usage
void test1(LPCTSTR lpclDevClass, LPCTSTR lpclDevName)
{
    WRITE_STARTF(_T("*%s* %s"), lpclDevClass, lpclDevName);
}
void test2()
{
    WRITE_START;
}
```

any ideas on how I should do this? Thank you

Comment: There are problems with both `WriteLog` functions you've posted. In the first one, `sizeof(log)` yields the size of a `char *` (or `wchar_t *`), not the length of the string. Use `strlen` (or the `_t*` equivalent if you must support `TCHAR`) to determine string length. If `_stprintf_s` expands to the wide char version, trying to write a `char` using `%c` format specifier probably won't work (it needs to be a `wchar_t`). In the second version of the function, you've got narrow strings everywhere, but you're writing these to `wcout` instead of `cout`; why?

Comment: @Praetorian So I don't have to support both cout and wcout. I'd rather just support wcout that works with both narrow and wide. I plan on moving everything over to wide anyway to support UNICODE like this program is supposed to.

Comment: Then replace the `TCHAR` and `_t*` functions with the wide char versions; maybe the problem will go away.